# Gradle "problem occured evaluating root project. For input string: "=10"

Tags: java, git, scala, gradle

I am trying to install BEAM, an extention on MatSim through the GIT Bash and I keep running into this error. This is exactly what I get:

```
$ gradle classes
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'K:\beam\build.gradle' line: 414

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'beam'.
> For input string: "=10"

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 16s
```

The stacktrace is too big to put in the body, but I could include a screenshot if needed.

This is my build.gradle:

```
import java.time.Instant
import java.time.ZoneOffset
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'kr.motd.gradle', name: 'sphinx-gradle-plugin', version: '1.0.3.Final'
        classpath "jp.classmethod.aws:gradle-aws-plugin:0.35"
        classpath "com.github.viswaramamoorthy:gradle-util-plugins:0.1.0-RELEASE"
        classpath 'cz.alenkacz:gradle-scalafmt:1.7.0'
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:3.6.1'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.5"
    id "de.undercouch.download" version "3.2.0"
    id "org.scoverage" version "2.5.0"
    id 'maven-publish'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'kr.motd.sphinx'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'ManifestClasspath'
apply plugin: 'scalafmt'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.docker-java-application'

group = 'beam'
version = '0.8.0'

description = """"""

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

compileScala.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
def scalaBinaryVersion = "2.12"
def akkaBinaryVersion = "2.5.22"
def circeBinaryVersion = "0.7.1"
def slf4jVersion = "1.7.25"
def kamonVersion = "0.6.7"
def tscfgVersion = "0.9.4"

sourceSets.main.scala.srcDirs = ["src/main/scala", "src/main/java"]
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = []

sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs = []
sourceSets.test.scala.srcDirs = ["src/test/scala", "src/test/java"]

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir "src/main/resources"
        }
    }
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir "src/test/resources"
        }
    }
}

if (project.hasProperty('env')) {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            resources {
                srcDirs "test/input/" + project.getProperty('env')
            }
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/' }
       // maven { url "https://maven.geotoolkit.org/" }
        maven { url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases" }
        maven { url "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
        maven { url "https://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools" }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/matsim/matsim" }
        maven { url "https://maven.conveyal.com/" }
        maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
        maven { url "https://download.java.net/maven/2/" }
        maven { url "https://people.apache.org/repo/m1-ibiblio-rsync-repository/org.apache.axis2/" }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/andimarek/graphql-java" }
        maven { url "https://maven.geo-solutions.it" }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases" }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://nexus.onebusaway.org/content/groups/public/" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile(group: 'com.github.LBNL-UCB-STI', name: 'beam-utilities', version: 'v0.2.4') {
        exclude group: 'com.github.LBNL-UCB-STI', module: 'r5'
        exclude group: 'org.matsim', module: 'matsim'
    }

    ////////////////////////////
    // Java dependencies
    ////////////////////////////
    compile group: 'com.google.inject', name: 'guice', version: '4.1.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.inject.extensions', name: 'guice-assistedinject', version: '4.1.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.inject.extensions', name: 'guice-multibindings', version: '4.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-math3', version: '3.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'fluent-hc', version: '4.5.2'

    // Apache 2.0
    compile group: 'com.univocity', name: 'univocity-parsers', version: '2.8.1'

    // LGPL
    compile group: 'org.geotools', name: 'gt-main', version: '13.0'
    compile group: 'org.geotools', name: 'gt-shapefile', version: '13.0'
    compile group: 'org.geotools', name: 'gt-referencing', version: '15.2'
    compile group: 'org.geotools', name: 'gt-epsg-wkt', version: '15.2'
    compile group: 'org.jfree', name: 'jfreechart', version: '1.0.14'

    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.9.4'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-scala_2.12', version: '2.9.4'
    compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'
    compile group: 'jdom', name: 'jdom', version: '1.1'
    compile group: 'org.jdom', name: 'jdom2', version: '2.0.5'
    compile 'com.hubspot.jinjava:jinjava:2.0.5'
    compile group: 'org.yaml', name: 'snakeyaml', version: '1.18'

    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
    compile 'net.sf.supercsv:super-csv:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.10'
    compile group: 'javax.annotation', name: 'javax.annotation-api', version: '1.2-b01'
    compile group: 'com.github.stephenc.eaio-uuid', name: "uuid", version: "3.4.0"

    compile "org.jgrapht:jgrapht-core:1.3.0"

    compile ('com.github.LBNL-UCB-STI:or-tools-wrapper:7.5-0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java'
    }

    // GPLv3
    compile group: 'org.matsim.contrib', name: 'multimodal', version: '0.10.0'
    compile group: 'org.matsim.contrib', name: 'bicycle', version: '0.10.0'

    compile(group: 'org.matsim.contrib', name: 'decongestion', version: '0.11.0-2018w44') {
        exclude group: 'org.matsim', module: 'matsim'
    }

    compile(group: 'com.github.wrashid.matsim', name: 'matsim', version: '0.10.1-beam-11') {
        exclude group: 'log4j', module: 'log4j'
    }

    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:${slf4jVersion}"
    compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
    compile "com.typesafe.scala-logging:scala-logging_${scalaBinaryVersion}:3.9.0"
    compile "org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:${slf4jVersion}"

    compile(group: 'com.github.michaz', name: 'r5', version: '3ab4fa04') {
        exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-simple'
    }

    compile "com.sigopt:sigopt-java:4.9.0"

    compile("com.uber:h3:3.4.1")

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.8'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-inline', version: '2.27.0'
    testCompile group: "org.mockito", name: "mockito-core", version: "2.+"

    /////////////////////////////////
    // Scala dependencies
    /////////////////////////////////

    // CORE Scala //
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.10"
    compile group: 'org.scala-lang.modules', name: "scala-xml_${scalaBinaryVersion}", version: '1.0.6'

    // NEEDED FOR USING REPL //
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.12.10"

    // TEST Scala //
    testCompile group: 'org.scalatest', name: "scalatest_${scalaBinaryVersion}", version: '3.0.8'
    testRuntime "org.pegdown:pegdown:1.4.2" // HTML report for scalatest

    // 3rd Party Scala //

    compile group: 'org.jliszka', name: 'probability-monad_2.11', version: '1.0.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beachape/enumeratum_2.12
    compile group: 'com.beachape', name: "enumeratum_${scalaBinaryVersion}", version: "1.5.12"
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beachape/enumeratum-circe_2.12
    compile group: 'com.beachape', name: "enumeratum-circe_${scalaBinaryVersion}", version: "1.5.14"

    compile "com.github.scopt:scopt_${scalaBinaryVersion}:3.7.0"
    compile "net.codingwell:scala-guice_${scalaBinaryVersion}:4.1.0"  // DI
    compile('com.github.carueda:tscfg:v' + tscfgVersion) { // config
        exclude group: 'org.scala-lang.modules', module: 'scala-xml_2.11'
    }
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.circe/circe-core_2.12
    compile group: 'io.circe', name: "circe-core_${scalaBinaryVersion}", version: circeBinaryVersion
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.circe/circe-generic_2.12
    compile group: 'io.circe', name: "circe-generic_${scalaBinaryVersion}", version: circeBinaryVersion
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.circe/circe-parser_2.12
    compile group: 'io.circe', name: "circe-parser_${scalaBinaryVersion}", version: circeBinaryVersion

    compile group: 'com.typesafe.play', name: "play-json_${scalaBinaryVersion}", version: '2.6.3'
    compile (group: 'com.github.romix.akka', name: "akka-kryo-serialization_${scalaBinaryVersion}", version: '0.5.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.esotericsoftware', module: 'kryo'
    }
    compile group: 'com.esotericsoftware', name: 'kryo', version: '4.0.2'

    compile "com.github.vagmcs:optimus_${scalaBinaryVersion}:3.1.0"
    compile "com.github.vagmcs:optimus-solver-oj_${scalaBinaryVersion}:3.1.0"

    ////////////////////////////////////
    ///Performance Monitoring (Kamon)///
    ////////////////////////////////////

    compile("io.kamon:kamon-core_${scalaBinaryVersion}:${kamonVersion}")
    compile("io.kamon:kamon-scala_${scalaBinaryVersion}:${kamonVersion}")
    compile("io.kamon:kamon-akka-2.4_${scalaBinaryVersion}:${kamonVersion}")
    compile("io.kamon:kamon-statsd_${scalaBinaryVersion}:${kamonVersion}")
    compile "io.kamon:kamon-influxdb_${scalaBinaryVersion}:0.6.9"
    compile("io.kamon:kamon-log-reporter_${scalaBinaryVersion}:${kamonVersion}")

    /////////////
    // Akka Dependencies
    ////////////

    // CORE Akka //
    compile group: 'com.typesafe.akka', name: "akka-actor_${scalaBinaryVersion}", version: akkaBinaryVersion
    compile group: 'com.typesafe.akka', name: "akka-slf4j_${scalaBinaryVersion}", version: akkaBinaryVersion
    //compile group: 'com.typesafe.akka', name: "akka-persistence_${scalaBinaryVersion}", version: akkaBinaryVersion
    //compile group: 'com.typesafe.akka', name: "akka-remote_${scalaBinaryVersion}", version: akkaBinaryVersion
    compile group: 'com.typesafe.akka', name: "akka-cluster_${scalaBinaryVersion}", version: akkaBinaryVersion
    compile group: 'com.typesafe.akka', name: "akka-contrib_${scalaBinaryVersion}", version: akkaBinaryVersion
    //compile group: 'org.iq80.leveldb', name: 'leveldb', version: '0.9'

    compile group: 'com.typesafe.akka', name: "akka-http_${scalaBinaryVersion}", version: "10.1.8"
    compile group: 'de.heikoseeberger', name: "akka-http-circe_${scalaBinaryVersion}", version: "1.25.2"

    // TEST Akka //
    testCompile group: 'com.typesafe.akka', name: "akka-testkit_${scalaBinaryVersion}", version: akkaBinaryVersion

    // 3rd Party Akka //
    //compile group: 'org.iq80.leveldb', name: 'leveldb', version: '0.7'
    //compile group: 'org.fusesource.leveldbjni', name: 'leveldbjni-all', version: '1.8'
    //compile group: 'com.google.protobuf', name: 'protobuf-java', version: '2.5.0'

    scoverage "org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-plugin_${scalaBinaryVersion}:1.3.1", "org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-runtime_${scalaBinaryVersion}:1.3.1"

    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.18'

    compile group: 'de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki', name: 'elki', version:'0.7.5'

    compile group: 'com.zaxxer', name: 'nuprocess', version: '1.2.4'

    def parquet = "1.10.0"
    compile group: 'org.apache.parquet', name: 'parquet-hadoop', version: parquet
    compile group: 'org.apache.parquet', name: 'parquet-avro', version: parquet
    compile (group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-client', version: '2.7.3') {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
        // Exclude `ASM` because it is binary incompatible with the one which is gotten from `com.conveyal:kryo-tools`: `org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.4`
        exclude group: 'asm', module: 'asm'
    }
}

// Autoformatting using scalafmt

scalafmt {
    // configFilePath = ".scalafmt.conf" // .scalafmt.conf in the project root is default value, provide only if other location is needed
}


configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails dependencyResolveDetails ->
            final requestedDependency = dependencyResolveDetails.requested
            if (requestedDependency.name != 'beam-utilities') {
                force 'javax.media:jai_core:1.1.3'
            }
        }
    }
    exclude group: 'javax.media', module: 'jai_codec'
    exclude group: 'javax.media', module: 'jai_imageio'

}

//compileScala.dependsOn(scalafmtAll)


// Task to run scala tests, as Scala tests not picked up by Gradle by default.
task spec(dependsOn: ['testClasses'], type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'org.scalatest.tools.Runner'
    args = ['-R', 'build/classes/scala/test', '-h', 'build/scalatest-report', '-oD', '-l', 'beam.tags.ExcludeRegular']
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
}
build.dependsOn spec

/* //////////////////////////////////////////////////
*  Task to run tagged tests.
*  Note: use space separated list of tags
* ./gradlew taggedTest -Ptags="beam.tags.Performance beam.tags.Integration"
* /////////////////////////////////////////////////// */

task taggedTest(dependsOn: ['testClasses'], type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'org.scalatest.tools.Runner'
    args = ['-R', 'build/classes/scala/test', '-o', '-n'] << (project.findProperty('tags') ?: 'org.scalatest.Ignore')
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
}

task specificTest(dependsOn: ['testClasses'], type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'org.scalatest.tools.Runner'
    args = ['-R', 'build/classes/scala/test', '-o', '-s'] << (project.findProperty('suite') ?: 'org.scalatest.Ignore')
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Task to run tests periodically on continue integration server.
// ./gradlew  periodicTest -Pconfig=test/input/sf-light/sf-light-1k.conf -Piterations=1
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
task periodicTest(dependsOn: ['testClasses'], type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'org.scalatest.tools.Runner'
    args = ['-R', 'build/classes/scala/test', '-o', '-n', 'beam.tags.Periodic'] <<
            (project.hasProperty('config') ? '-Dconfig=' + project.findProperty('config') :
                    (project.hasProperty('iterations') ? '-Diterations=' + project.findProperty('iterations') : '')) <<
            (project.hasProperty('config') && project.hasProperty('iterations') ?
                    '-Diterations=' + project.findProperty('iterations') : '')
    jvmArgs = ['-javaagent:build/aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar']
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    doFirst() {
        if (!project.file('build/aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar').exists()) {
            download {
                src 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.10/aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar'
                dest buildDir
            }
        }
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Generate config classes reflecting the application.conf file
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
task generateConfig {
    doLast {
        def tscfgJarFile = project.file('build/tscfg-' + tscfgVersion + '.jar')
        if (!tscfgJarFile.exists() || !tscfgJarFile.isFile()) {
            download {
                src 'https://github.com/carueda/tscfg/releases/download/v' + tscfgVersion + '/tscfg-' + tscfgVersion + '.jar'
                dest buildDir
            }
        }
        javaexec {
            main = "-jar"
            args = [
                    "build/tscfg-${tscfgVersion}.jar",
                    "--spec", "src/main/resources/beam-template.conf",
                    "--scala",
                    "--pn", "beam.sim.config",
                    "--cn", "BeamConfig",
                    "--dd", "src/main/scala/beam/sim/config/"
            ]
        }
    }
}

task repl(type: JavaExec) {
    main = "scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner"
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput System.in
    args '-usejavacp'
}

task deleteSf {
    doLast {
        if (project.file('production/application-sfbay/r5/network.dat').exists()) {
            delete 'production/application-sfbay/r5/network.dat'
        }
        if (project.file('production/application-sfbay/r5/osm.mapdb').exists()) {
            delete 'production/application-sfbay/r5/osm.mapdb'
        }
        if (project.file('production/application-sfbay/r5/osm.mapdb.p').exists()) {
            delete 'production/application-sfbay/r5/osm.mapdb.p'
        }
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Run Via application plugin
// Note: colon preceding "run" is necessary to only run the main project and not launch the GUI as well.
// ./gradlew :run -PappArgs="['--config', 'production/application-sfbay/beam.conf']"
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
mainClassName = "beam.sim.RunBeam"


def myAvailableRam = (System.getenv("MAXRAM") ?: (project.findProperty('maxRAM') ?: "140")).toString().replace("g", "").toInteger()


def getCurrentTimestamp = {
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy_HH-mm-ss")
            .withLocale(Locale.US)
            .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .format(Instant.now())
}

def logGC = ["-XX:+PrintGCDetails", "-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps", "-Xloggc:gc_${getCurrentTimestamp()}.log"]

// Use following for remote debug mode
def remoteDebug = ["-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8005"]

def jfr = ["-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures", "-XX:+FlightRecorder",
           "-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,disk=true,maxage=10h,dumponexit=true,loglevel=info"]

// On the running machine there should be file /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr/profile_heap_exception.jfc  with content from
// https://pastebin.com/N3uuUfPz - it's Java Mission Control with metrics about heap allocation and details about exceptions
def jfrWithMem = ["-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures", "-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions", "-XX:+DebugNonSafepoints",
                  "-XX:StartFlightRecording=delay=2s,duration=60m,name=mem_ex,filename=recording.jfr,settings=profile_heap_exception",
                  "-XX:+FlightRecorder", "-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=disk=true,maxage=10h,dumponexit=true,loglevel=info"]


def jmx = ["-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9005", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=127.0.0.1",
           "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=true", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false",
           "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true", "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1"]

// UseParallelGC
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Xmx${myAvailableRam}g", "-Xms${myAvailableRam/2}g",
                             "-XX:+UseParallelGC", "-XX:+UseParallelOldGC", "-XX:MetaspaceSize=150M", "-Djava.awt.headless=true",
                             "-Dlogback.configurationFile=logback_prod.xml", "-Xss2048k"] + logGC + jmx

println(applicationDefaultJvmArgs)

run {
    if (project.hasProperty("appArgs")) {
        args Eval.me(appArgs)
    }

    doFirst() {
        if (!project.file('build/aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar').exists()) {
            download {
                src 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.10/aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar'
                dest buildDir
            }
        }
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Run ExperimentGenerator from Command line
//  gradle :execute -PmainClass=beam.experiment.ExperimentGenerator -PappArgs="['--experiments', 'test/input/beamville/example-experiment/experiment.yml']"
// Run R5 GUI server
//  gradle --stacktrace :execute -PmainClass=com.conveyal.r5.R5Main -PappArgs="['point','--graphs','production/application-sfbay/r5/']"
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

task execute(type: JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs = applicationDefaultJvmArgs
    if (project.hasProperty("mainClass")) {
        main = mainClass
    } else {
        main = mainClassName
    }
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    if (project.hasProperty("appArgs")) {
        args Eval.me(appArgs)
    }
    doFirst() {
        if (!project.file('build/aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar').exists()) {
            download {
                src 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.10/aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar'
                dest buildDir
            }
        }
    }
}


task matsimConversion(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'beam.utils.matsim_conversion.MatsimConversionTool'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    environment "PWD", "na"
    if (project.hasProperty("confPath")) {
        args Eval.me(confPath)
        // if this triggers an error, try
        // args "${confPath}"
    }
}

task generateDocumentation(type: JavaExec) {
    group 'Documentation'
    description 'Format the data using Sphinx RST formats'

    main = 'beam.docs.GenerateDocumentationTask'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}

tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    // Enable Scala warnings output
    scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = ["-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-feature", "-Xfatal-warnings"]
}

task fmt(dependsOn: scalafmtAll) 
task checkScalaFmt() {
    doLast {
        try {
            def workingDir = new File("${project.projectDir}")
            def result = 'git diff --exit-code'.execute(null, workingDir)
            result.waitFor()
            if (result.exitValue() != 0) throw new Exception("""
Please run ./gradlew scalaFmtAll and commit/push the subsequent results to fix this error.
This happened because a git diff yielded a non-zero exit code. 
This task was built to be run on the CI server AFTER scalaFmtAll
It should only error if the results of scalaFmtAll resulted in code modifications.
And that would only happen if the committed code is not formatted as expected.""")
        } catch (e) {
            throw new Exception("An unexpected error was encountered while checking that scalaFmtAll was committed.", e)
        }
    }
}

docker{

    registryCredentials {
        url = 'https://index.docker.io/v1/'
        username = System.getenv("DOCKER_USER")
        password = System.getenv("DOCKER_PASSWORD")
    }

    javaApplication {
        baseImage = 'continuumio/miniconda3'
        maintainer = 'LBNL Beam Team'
        tag = "beammodel/beam:$version"
    }
}

dockerDistTar {
    instruction 'RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install openjdk-8-jdk && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*'
    addFile 'test/', 'test/'
}

dockerCopyDistResources {
    from('test/') {
        into('test/')
    }
}
```

Specifically line 414 is:

```
def myAvailableRam = (System.getenv("MAXRAM") ?: (project.findProperty('maxRAM') ?: "140")).toString().replace("g", "").toInteger()
```

Any help with this would be awesome, none of this is my own code, this is all cloned from a git repository that *should* be working.

Comment: Try to change the variable "MAXRAM" to another value, 4 for example

Comment: Are you using Windows? What commit do you have checked-out (`git rev-parse HEAD`)?

Comment: @Omer the git clone is: git clone git@github.com:LBNL-UCB-STI/beam.git and the checkout is: git checkout v0.7.0

Comment: @PedroCorreiaLuís the build was successful! Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: I'm now getting another error running one of the tests :(

Comment: With the 10 or the 4?

Comment: neither, I'm getting a "java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1", it seems like it can't find a lot of files that should be there :/

Comment: Seems like the repo you cloned should have specific instructions you missed or simply are lacking